# How the user process can access the character device loaded by my module

Tags: linux, unix, module, system-calls, ioctl

I am trying to load into the kernel a system-call dynamically (without restarting the kernel and compailing it) in an attempt to (once in kernel mode) write to user process's memory.

(I know there is a way to do this with the ptrace interface but it is not an option.)

I know the only way to do this is to load a module. In order to allow the user communicating with it, i was told to use a character device (which is supposed to be in /dev/, right?). I loaded one successfully.
My problem is that i don't know how the user process access it without an system call.
(i was told to use ioctl)
Could anyone show how a user process can call ioctl for example that was loaded by my module?

Thanks,
Shai

Answer (score 0):

> For the answer below, I have assumed you to be developing a Linux module.  Upon rereading your question, I see I could have misinterpreted the problem.

---

There are several mechanisms for communicating with a kernel driver:

- a `/proc` entry (aka *[procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs)*)
- *[ioctl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl)* through the device interface
- directly through the device interface

The most common technique is the last which uses `read()` and/or `write()` system calls to cause driver action.  While these system calls ordinarily pass pure data, there is nothing stopping a particular driver from instead passing [metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) through the i/o interface.

On the other hand, if the driver already has a useful pure data discipline for which `read()` and `write()` are not good for metadata, then the `ioctl()` system call is a kind of general purpose Swiss army knife for doing all kinds of things related to a file, such as loading or unloading a magnetic tape, ejecting a DVD, finding a network card's Ethernet address, or finding out how many disk drive errors have occurred.  There have been so many *ioctl* operation codes defined, you can probably find a reasonable one to reuse for your purposes.  A big disadvantage of the `ioctl` interface is that it is best suited for use by a custom program, so it would be awkward or difficult to transfer data through an `ioctl` connected to a pipeline of standard programs.

The `/proc` interface combines the best of the previous two techniques:  it is amenable to using `stdin`/`stdout` conventions with standard utility programs, but it also provides an interface to a device driver which is independent of any i/o through the regular driver mechanism.  For example, try `cat /proc/net/tcp` on your Linux system.  It shows the status of all `TCP` connections.

A good article on implementing the *procfs* feature is at [`create_proc_entry()`](http://buffer.antifork.org/linux/procfs-guide.pdf).  Implementing an ioctl is well covered [here](http://www.makelinux.com/ldd3/chp-6-sect-1).  The metadata approach is as easy to code as any other device driver, though it might present conceptual hurdles for an experienced implementer.